# FileNotFoundError for a file that is certainly there when running a command from a python script

Tags: python, awk, terminal, subprocess

I need to perform consecutive concatenations of FITS files (or one big concatenation of all of them) and, since doing them by hand is a terrible idea (around 200 files). I am using Python to write a script and then I run it in a WSL/UNIX terminal using `python3 code.py` on the command line.

The script accesses ascii tables that are in a subfolder (called `vvv_tiles_no_overlap`). Since I am running the script both on WSL on my Windows 11 PC for troubleshooting and on a UNIX terminal on a remote server for the real work, I use `os.getcwd()` and `os.path.join()` to create the paths that the script uses to access the files. So far, the code successfully completes the following tasks:

1. Using `awk`, access the file in the subfolder and create a temporary CSV file in the same directory (`tmp.csv`).
2. Using `stilts`, convert `tmp.csv` to FITS (`tmp.fits`).
3. Run a `stilts` command to cross-match the local catalogue to a remote one and save it as its individual FITS file inside the subfolder.

So far the code has no issues accessing the files and performing what it needs to do. Every command is called using `subprocess.call()`. Then, I ask the script to read every fits file created in the subfolder and concatenate them. When the code reaches that point, I get the following `FileNotFoundError`:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1 (process):       | time passed: 00:00:00
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/mnt/d/2023-2/awker-stiltser.py", line 183, in process
    subprocess.call(f'stilts tcat lazy=True in="{Ft_paths[0]} {Ft_paths[1]}" out=VVVxGAIA.fits')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 345, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 971, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 1863, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'stilts tcat lazy=True in="vvv_tiles_no_overlap/VVVxGAIA_b201.fits vvv_tiles_no_overlap/VVVxGAIA_b202.fits" out=VVVxGAIA.fits'
```

(The paths do not seem to be absolute because I changed the code around to see if `os` was somehow causing the problem, but I assure you that it changed nothing.)

I didn't understand how the file could not be found when the path was generated by the code itself. I double checked and finally ran the same call that is reported by `FileNotFoundError`:

```
stilts tcat lazy=True in="vvv_tiles_no_overlap/VVVxGAIA_b201.fits vvv_tiles_no_overlap/VVVxGAIA_b202.fits" out=VVVxGAIA.fits
```

The command ran without issue and I got the expected result. What could cause this problem?

Answer (score -1):

When I was double checking to check my question was clear, I noticed I hadn't added `shell=True` to the subprocess call. I have literally lost two days of work to this. I hope this helps anyone who needs it. I planned on linking to a pastebin with my code, but I feel it is no longer necessary.